# Can we specify an Escape Character when creating an external table on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool?

Tags: external-tables, azure-synapse-analytics

**Question:** Can we specify an Escape Character when creating an external table on **Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool**?

**Requirement:**
There is a need for an external table on a dedicated sql pool to be pointed to a CSV file on ADLS Gen2. The CSV file has the following properties:

*Column delimiter (The character used to separate columns in a file):* ***Pipe (|)***
*Quote character (The character used to quote column values if it contains column delimiter):*  ***Double quote (“)***
*Escape Character (The character used to escape quotes inside a quoted value):* ***Double quote (“)***

Based on above, I was trying to create an external table on Synapse Dedicated pool but I can't find any Microsoft documentation on how to set the property for Escape character. Here below is my **external file format** set and the table syntax -

[FileFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJ7h.png)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Test].[tblStaging_Page]
(
SessionID [INT] NOT NULL,
Date [Date] NOT NULL,
Article VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
Content VARCHAR(2000) NULL
)
WITH (
 LOCATION = '/Test/Inbound/Digital_Test/Page/Landing',
    DATA_SOURCE = ADLSGen2TestDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = DelimitedText_PipeTerminator_QuoteDelimiter_FirstRowAsHeader
);
```

When I create an external table without specifying an escape character, I get the error **'Could not find a delimiter after string delimiter'**. Therefore, I need to specify Escape character on my external table in order to overcome this issue. Below is the sample data for which I get the error -

```
SessionID|Date|Article|Content
13354|2023-03-15|"Home | Facebook"|"Content is about 'VVIP"" people"
```